# awk pattern: remove everything after space (including) in a field

Tags: regex, awk, substitution

Im completely new to AWK. I am trying to remove everything from after a space in a tab-separated file (from $1 in the below silly example), or grab everything before the first space and throw into a variable in awk (the same). So e.g. I have lines like

```
abc 0000    12sometext  stuff
```

How do I remove the `' 0000'` (could be any length, only rule is everything after first space in $1) and end up with $1 being `abc`. The sub-like functions are not in AWK but can I use a regular expression somehow?

If I need to assign the result `abc` to a variable it seems unnessesary to use the arrays from function split (in AWK), is there not another way ?

```
awk -F'\t' '{n = split($1, array, " "); result = array[1]; print result}' file.txt
```

Comment: I see ! but I wanted something along `awk -F'\t' '{name = gensub(/ .+/, "", $1); print name}' file.txt` I does not recognize this function to have the returned value.

Comment: There's a dozen different ways. Assuming that $0 is `abc 0000` then you could do any of: `var=substr($0,1,3)`, `var=substr($0,1,index($0," ")-1)`, `match($0,/ /) {var=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)}`, `var=gensub(/ .*/,"",1,$0)`, `var=$0; sub(/ .*/,"",var)`, `split($0,t,/ /); var=t[1]`, etc., etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` to replace everything after space in `$1`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub(/ .+/, "", $1)} 1' file

abc 12sometext  stuff
```

Comment: Could you explain the '1' after the sub statement ? And how can you assign the remaining part `abc`to a variable (to do something in the awk program) aka `short_name = sub(/ .+/, "", $1)`.

Comment: `1` is default action in `awk` so that we print the record. To assign replaced value to a variable use: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {p=$1; sub(/ .+/, "", p)} 1' file`

Comment: A clever! I get it.